# Prerequisites for sfu computer science undergraduate

Tags: computer-science

I graduated in 2022 and have not started post secondary yet. I wanted to apply for the computer science program at SFU but I was wondering how strict the prerequisites I need are. I have all the grade 11 needed courses but for grade 12 I have English 12, social Justice 12, and pre calculus 12. I’m planning on taking physics 12 and law 12 to reach the requirements but in pre calculus 12 I received a 57%. Should I look into retaking that course or do I still have a good chance of getting in if all my other courses are above a 70%.

Comment: Hi Ghazal, this isn't a good site to ask questions specific to you personal circumstances

Comment: Sorry, this is not the right site for your question.  Undergraduate admissions are off topic in general, and we don't handle questions about the rules of specific institutions.  You should contact the SFU admissions office with this question.

Comment: I have contacted sfu but due to their high volume of inquiries it could take up to 2 weeks to get an email back. I just wanted to see if anyone that is currently in the program has any input!

Comment: @GhazalMahdavian It's clear what you want; the problem is that you're not asking in an appropriate place, because undergraduate admissions is off-topic here.